# On what page is my row displayed?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pagination, sqlalchemy

I have a table of posts. I display the list of posts paginated organized by time descending with each page limited to 20 rows. How do I figure out what page a specific row is by id is on so I can link to that specific page.

Table `post`

```
CREATE TABLE post
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  text character varying(1000),
  created_date timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT post_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Current

```
select * from post order by created_date desc limit 20 offset 0
```

What page is id X on? My theory is I can return the row number the id is on when you select by the specific 'order by' but I'm not sure if that's right or how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT rn / 20 + 1 AS page  -- 20 rows per page
FROM  (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS rn
   FROM   post
   ) sub
WHERE id = 123;
```

The usual disclaimer: page numbers can change if underlying data changes (concurrently).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single link and if the `created_date` is always the inserting `current_timestamp` then it can be done counting the `serial` id

```
select count(*) / 20 + 1 as page
from post
where id >= %(id)s
```

To make it easier to always have the `current_timestamp` as the `created_date` make it the default

```
created_date timestamp default current_timestamp
```

It is possible to make it a constraint

```
created_date timestamp default current_timestamp check(created_date = current_timestamp)
```

If you need a list of links pass the ids as a Python list to the query

```
select *
from (
    select id, count(*) over(order by id desc) / 20 + 1 as page
    from post
    where
        id >= (
            select id
            from unnest(%(ids_list)s) s
            order by id
            limit 1
        )
) s
where id = any (%(ids_list))s
```

In this last query `count` is a running total.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d6ae/2)